# Reporting effect aize

Tags: terminology, effect-size

Could someone please explain the difference between standard mean difference and adjusted mean difference. I want a common rubric for reporting effect size.

Answer (score 0):

A standardized mean difference divides the mean difference by the pooled within groups standard deviation (see Cohen's d). Thus, it is standardizing the difference relative to the standard deviation. An adjusted mean difference is the difference between two means that have been adjusted for covariates, such as baseline differences. This difference, however, remains in the units of the original scale. You can, of course, standardized an adjusted mean difference.